# declarative form and grammatical structure

Tags: declarative-questions

I'm not sure about the meaning and grammatical structure of the following sentence. Can I add "related" after "more" and before "to babies" to make it more straightforward in translation? If I want to transform it to declarative form, could it be "...there is more (related) to babies and how we relate them that..."?

> So, whether you are a father or mother, is there more to babies and how we relate to them that could make this experience a great deal more interesting, both for the parent and the baby?

Cooper, A., & Redfern, S. (2015). Reflective parenting: A guide to understanding what's going on in your child's mind. Routledge.

Comment: It's a bad sentence to begin with, because after "whether you're a father or a mother", we expect a statement, not a question. Also, it suggests there might be a difference between being a mother or a father in terms of this question, which doesn't make sense either. So after adding other words to it, it still won't be good

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, its rather oddly phrased. I'll do my best.

There is an idioim "there is more to something", used in expressions like "There is more to him than meets the eye".  It means that there is greater complexity to something.

> There's more to calculus than just changing the power by one, but many students never understand this.

In your sentence the writer is discussing "[the topic of] babies and how we relate to them", and the implied singular nature of "the topic" justifies the use of the singular verb.  "Is there more to [the topic of] babies ..."

The question is rhetorical, and it is clear that the author is strongly suggesting that the answer is "Yes, there is!", and you should reach the same conclusion regardless of your gender (whether you are a mother or father).

But Gotube is right to say that the sentence could and should have been completely rephrased.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. If you were to rephrase the sentence to a more straightforward format, how did you rewrite it?

Comment: I'd probably split it into separate parts.  But as I'm not sure of the wider context of the quote I don't think I can give a definitive answer to that.

Comment: I understand your point, but according to current information, if you want to transform it to a declarative simple form, how do you rewrite the first part containing "there is more to something"(I mean "There is more to babies and how we relate to them that could make this experience a great deal more interesting")?